# Binding sum of a column of a datagrid to a formitem's text in Flex3

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, datagrid, flex3, mxml

I want to bind sum of a column of a datagrid to a FormItem'text which is shown below of that datagrid. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a loop to parse your dataProvider to build the total and then put that total in your form item.

You can add valuecommit event on your datagrid and call your script to build the sum.

Comment: Than you @Epharion. Its working Properly.I have a doubt, I am going to bind realtime data to the datagrid.  Is valuecommit event called whenever the datagrid's data changes?

Comment: Yes valueCommit is dispatched when values are changed programmatically or by user interaction.

Comment: Thank you once again @Epharion :)